# What is the difference between lures and incense in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

So as far as i'm aware, lures and incense do the same thing. They both attract Pokemon for 30 minutes. So is there a difference or is it just two items that do the same thing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lures can be attached to a pokestop, and all trainers can go there and find more pokemon spawning.
Incenses can be activated anywhere and only spawn pokemon for you.